# lein uberjar - No configuration setting found for key 'akka.version'

Tags: clojure, akka, leiningen

I can create an uberjar that is composed of lots of class files, originally Scala, Java, Clojure. The problem I have is that when I run `java -jar my-server.jar` it crashes with:

```
No configuration setting found for key 'akka.version'
```

This is to be expected and has a [maven solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30597376/apache-spark-akka-version-error-by-build-jar-with-all-dependencies). The yellow writing on the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011243/no-configuration-setting-found-for-key-akka-version) is basically Akka saying "you shouldn't build uberjars with Akka jars in them, as then Akka won't be able to find its `.conf` files."

I am trying this as a lein solution:

```
:pom-plugins [[org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-shade-plugin 2.2]]
```

I have a local maven repository (by this I mean not the ~/.m2 one, but a local one that is used to introduce non-Clojars jars into the lein build). Maybe I need to `lein deploy localrepo1` for the akka jars again to pick up this new setting - Nope - that didn't help.

Here's some of the stack trace to make it clear where the problem comes from:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka.version'
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:124)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:145)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:151)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:159)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:164)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getString(SimpleConfig.java:206)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:169)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:505)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:142)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:109)
    at com.seasoft.comms.MyPLCActorHolder.createRefToLocalActor(MyPLCActorHolder.scala:39)
```

*Edit* I've now looked inside the jar files. There are two akka jar files that both have a `reference.conf` in them. These files are not correctly merged because (unsurprisingly) `lein uberjar` doesn't understand the nesting of the property key/values within them.

Specifically the `reference.conf` in `akka-actor_2.11-2.3.9.jar` has `akka.version = "2.3.9"`, but this entry has not made it to the merged `reference.conf`. I altered the uberjar and that fixed the problem, of course giving me the next merge problem. So the fix here is to manually do the merge myself.

And the better fix would be to write a little merging program (with two functions: a predicate and merge) and get it into akka so that people who write build tools can just use it...

Comment: Does your `project.clj` contain that `akka.version` key?

Comment: I see what you are saying. I don't think it is a lein `key` required. The message is basically Akka saying that it can't see its own configuration file with the version in it. Apparently all would be fine if I used `lein jar` instead. But I had other issues with that approach.

Comment: I'm a Scala developer and I can tell you that the error you posted comes from the usage of a common library for getting properties for Scala called Typesafe Config (github.com/typesafehub/config).
You should have `.conf` file in your classpath containing that key.

Comment: I'm new to uberjars. All the config files get put at the top level in the uberjar. There is a reference.conf, which has various Akka settings, but no `version` String is in there. This is working code by the way, I'm just giving it a Clojure 'skin'.

Comment: I might need a closer look at the project structure to help you further.
Would it be easy for you to sketch the project directory tree?

Comment: Now I'm confused because the 'yellow writing' (Akka doco) says that merging is the answer, and it seems merging has already been done in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Manually merging `reference.conf` from the two jars and then manually altering the uberjar (overwriting the existing `reference.conf`) did the trick. The merged file is [here](https://github.com/chrismurrph/alarm-server/blob/master/merge/reference.conf).

I believe this problem will occur anytime there are property files that come from different jars that have the same name. For instance `log4j.properties` also needed to be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I changed spark version to avoid this kind of problem. [Spark 2.1.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10/2.1.0) does not depend on Akka, and does not have the Akka `reference.conf` problem.